# Where is $|x|^x$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let 
>   $$
> f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
> |x|^x &\mbox{ if $x \neq0$} \\
> 1 &\mbox{if  $x=0$}
> \end{array} \right.
> $$
>
> Where is $x$ differentiable?

I feel like it is differentiable everywhere apart from $x=0$, but struggle to see how to make that more concrete.

Comment: Consider the case $x^x$ with $x>0$ first.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $f(x)=e^{x \log |x|}$. Considering basic results with respect to the differentiability of of the composition and product of differentiable functions, you just need to determine where  $g(x)= \log|x|$ is differentiable. In fact, $g(x)$ (and therefore $f(x)$) is differentiable for $x \ne 0$ and $g'(x)=\frac 1x$.

Answer (score 1):

Away from $x=0$, $|x|^x$ is a smooth function. At $x=0$,
\begin{align} \frac{|0+h|^{0+h}-1}h &= \frac{e^{h\log |h|} - 1}h \\&= \frac{h\log|h| + O(h^2(\log|h|)^2)}{h} \\&= \log|h| + O(h(\log |h|)^2)\\&\to -\infty \quad (h\to 0)\end{align}
So its not differentiable at 0. But you might be fooled by its graph-[image]
Its "quite close" to being differentiable, belonging to every Hölder space $C^\alpha$, $(0<\alpha<1)$, and the minor variant $|x|^{x|x|^\epsilon}$ is actually differentiable the moment $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the limit of $$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$ this means $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|^h-1}{h}$$. Now we disinguish two cases:
$$h>0$$ we have $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{h^h-1}{h}=-\infty$$ and $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{(-h)^h-1}{h}=-\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^x \ ,\forall x>0  ;$

$f(x)=1, \ x=0;$

$f(x)=(-x)^x \ \forall x<0;$

you must solve the limits:

$ \lim _{x\to 0,x>0} \frac {x^x-1}{x} =\lim _{x\to 0,x>0} \frac {e^{\log (x^x)}-1}{x}=\lim _{x\to 0,x>0} \frac {e^{x\log (x)}-1}{x} = \lim _{x\to 0,x>0} \frac {e^{x\log (x)}-1}{x\log (x)}*\frac {x\log (x)}{x}$ and $x\log (x)\rightarrow 0$ then $\frac {e^{x\log (x)}-1}{x\log (x)}\rightarrow1$ and $\frac {x\log (x)}{x}\rightarrow0$ then$\lim _{x\to 0,x>0} \frac {x^x-1}{x}=-\infty$

$ \lim _{x\to 0,x<0} \frac {(-x)^x-1}{x}=...=-\infty$ Because limits are eqal $f$ is diff